# does oracle10g client( version 10.2.0.0) compatible with windows server 2008 standard 32 bit service pack 2

Tags: oracle10g, windows-server-2008

I am trying to install oracle 10g client version 10.2.0.0 on windows server 2008 standard 32 bit machine with service pack 2. The oracle 10g client is getting installed but when i try to connect to oracle 9i server on another machine it is giving error "test does not succeeded". I have tested same using windows 7. On that it is working fine and getting connected to oracle 9i server. But i want this to be done on windows server 2008 standard only. Please suggest what i can do in this case?

Comment: Which test does not succeed - how are you connecting? What connection settings (URL, or host, port, SID/service name) are you using and how do those compare to the working Wun7 client and the server listener? What credentials are you using? What actual error message (an ORA- or TNS- error code and message) do you get? There is nowhere near enough information here to guess what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Host is the IP of the oracle 9i server machine

Comment: Host is the IP address of the oracle 9i server machine.Service name is orcl.world. SID is ORACLE. Listener service is running on 9i server machine. It is getting connected from the machine having windows 7 machine using oracle net manager. But when i try configure it using 10g client Net manager on windows server 2008 machine and after adding all the information when i test for the connection it shows "The test did not succeed".

Comment: [It really doesn't give you a more detailed error](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/connect.htm#NETAG373), on screen or in a log? If all the connection information, including the username and password you're supplying, is identical and entered correctly then can the Windows box see the DB server box - can you ping it, and can you telnet to the listener port? Maybe there's a firewall blocking you, for example.

Comment: The error is "The test did not succeed. There may be an error in fields entered or a server may not be ready for connection". I am getting the ping from the server machine as well as can access the folders in it also. I have checked the listener and oracle service are running on the server properly. Also, there is no firewall or antivirus active on the server 2008 machine. Is there any possibility that if i use VMWare windows2008 server instead of physical machine? because the machine on which i am doing it is actually windows 7 machine having windows server2008.

Comment: Also, instead of being VMWare machine i can get the ping from server machine and also can access its folders too. So, i am sure there is no issue with the connectivity.